# Is always possible to win King + Queen vs. King + Rook?

Tags: endgame, rooks, queens

Does every situation (except where the Queen team gets mated or the Queen is captured immediately) result in a win for the Queen team? Or can the Rook team, by perfect play, force a stalemate?

Comment: There should be positions on 16x16 board where queen can't break defense, but on standard 8x8 any draw or loss is caused only by immediate tactics

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Mate is always possible, except in the cases you've outlined already. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Pawnless_chess_endgame&oldid=787502347#Queen_versus_rook):

> A queen wins against a lone rook, unless there is an immediate draw by stalemate or due to perpetual check (Nunn 2002a:49) (or if the rook or king can immediately capture the queen). ... With perfect play, in the worst winning position, the queen can win the rook or checkmate within 31 moves (Müller & Lamprecht 2001:400).

Comment: When did that change? I could have sworn the worst case for queen vs rook took 127 moves?

Comment: @Shufflepants I think you've misremembered. Thomas Ströhlein solved KQ-KR by tablebases in 1970, [according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endgame_tablebase#Background).